# How to sort ListBox items alphabetically in WinRT?

Tags: c#, sorting, listbox, windows-8, windows-runtime

In Windows RT, the ListBox seems to be missing the Sort method. How would I sort the items alphabetically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sort the list it's bound on, usually by sorting the list directly, since sorting and filtering the [ICollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.icollectionview) have been omitted in WinRT. See [Creating a Sorted Collection View in WinRT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649532/creating-a-sorted-collection-view-in-winrt) for more information.

Comment: Sorting and filtering are the responsibilities of the view model.  Sorting prior to placing data in the view model is taking us back at least a decade in terms of architecture.  In addition, anyone developing live data applications are going to see an unacceptable amount of refreshing when the list resets with every change.

Comment: @DRAirey1 I agree. However, WinRT does not support sorting and filtering ICollectionView, unlike WPF. Downvote WinRT, not the correct answer :-).

Comment: "You sort the list it's bound on, usually by sorting the list directly" is not an answer to the OP's question.  This link has a more acceptable answer: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/527686/A-WinRT-CollectionView-class-with-Filtering-and-So.  It begs the question: is Microsoft trying to alienate WPF developers?  It would have been trivial for the MS team to give this job to an intern and would have make our life less of a living hell trying to create MVVM applications for the tablet.